# How to build a content page dynamically taking different user inputs depending on XML page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm building an APP in Xamarin. The idea is my user needs to send a request to a server to perform some work. The server's services are exposed as Web Services. I can retrieve the XML from the different Webservices.

I want to build an interface for the user to fill in the necessary inputs for my Webservice to successfully accept a call.

I have already been able to generate a list of available services using ListView.

```
        items = new List<Item>();
        String htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://localhost:8181/ws/");
        String BusinessObjectStr;
        BusinessObjectStr = htmlCode.Substring(htmlCode.IndexOf("<b>"));

        String[] BusinessObjectList = Regex.Split(BusinessObjectStr, "<b>");
        foreach (string item in BusinessObjectList)
        {
            if (item.Length > 0)
            {
                string tempDesc = item.Substring(item.IndexOf("</b>") + 7, item.IndexOf("<br>"));
                tempDesc = tempDesc.Substring(0,tempDesc.IndexOf("<br>"));
                items.Add(new Item { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Text = item.Substring(0, item.IndexOf("</b>")), Description = tempDesc});
            }
        }
```

My next struggle is for each of the available services, I need to take in different inputs. I could not get that working using ListView and I looked at TableView. TableView could give me the result, however, It is static as I need to define it upfront.

```
        <TableView>
        <TableRoot>
            <TableSection Title="{Binding Header1}">
                <EntryCell Label="{Binding Value2}" Placeholder="default" />
                <EntryCell Label="{Binding Value3}" Placeholder="omg brb ttyl gtg lol" Keyboard="Chat" />
                <EntryCell Label="{Binding Value4}" Placeholder="sales@xamarin.com" Keyboard="Email" />
                <EntryCell Label="{Binding Value5}" Placeholder="55" Keyboard="Numeric" />
```

The Webservice XML are structured like this:

```
   <wsdl:message name="InitialiseRequest"/>
   <wsdl:message name="InitialiseResponse">
       <wsdl:part name="Instance" type="s:string"/>
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:message name="CleanUpRequest">
       <wsdl:part name="Instance" type="s:string"/>
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:message name="CleanUpResponse"/>
   <wsdl:message name="AddNumbersRequest">
       <wsdl:part name="Instance" type="s:string"/>
       <wsdl:part name="Value1" type="s:decimal"/>
       <wsdl:part name="Value2" type="s:decimal"/>
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:message name="AddNumbersResponse">
       <wsdl:part name="Result" type="s:decimal"/>
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:message name="SubtractNumbersRequest">
       <wsdl:part name="Instance" type="s:string"/>
       <wsdl:part name="Value1" type="s:decimal"/>
       <wsdl:part name="Value2" type="s:decimal"/>
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:message name="SubtractNumbersResponse">
       <wsdl:part name="Result" type="s:decimal"/>
   </wsdl:message>
```

In this scenario, my Developer has exposed a service to AddNumbers and SubtractNumbers.

I want to build a page with an area: "AddNumberRequest"
which take two inputs: "Value1" and "Value2"

and an area: "SubtractNumbersRequest"
which take two inputs: "Value1" and "Text1"

As you can imagine the developer here made a mistake by asking the user for "Text1" instead of "Value2" when doing "SubtractNumbers". If the Developer changed this code, the Webservice would automatically change, hence, my Apps should ask the user for the changed type.

"Instance" is generated automatic by my app, hence, I will not show it to the user.

Additional:
Below is simply all the types that I need to be able to create an input for, as my developer can choose among those:

```
   <wsdl:message name="InputAllTypesRequest">
       <wsdl:part name="Instance" type="s:string"/>
       <wsdl:part name="Value" type="s:decimal"/>
       <wsdl:part name="Flag" type="s:boolean"/>
       <wsdl:part name="Date" type="s:date"/>
       <wsdl:part name="DateTime" type="s:dateTime"/>
       <wsdl:part name="Text" type="s:string"/>
       <wsdl:part name="Password" type="s:string"/>
       <wsdl:part name="Time" type="s:time"/>
       <wsdl:part name="TimeSpan" type="s:duration"/>
       <wsdl:part name="Binary" type="s:base64Binary"/>
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:message name="InputAllTypesResponse">
       <wsdl:part name="Result" type="s:decimal"/>
   </wsdl:message>
```

Can anyone help me with a direction to go for, or a code example. I'm quite new to Xamarin, but above issue, I have not been able to crack by searching the net.

Comment: you're not going to be able to dynamically build a UI in XAML, but it's fairly simple to do with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're not going to be able to dynamically build a UI in XAML, but it's fairly simple to do with code.  Conceptually, you would just loop through your list of controls, create each one dynamically, then add it to your layout

```
StackLayout stack = new StackLayout();

// controls is an array or list that defines your control data
foreach (var c in controls) 
{
  switch (c.Type) 
  {
    case "Text":
      var control = new Entry();
      stack.Add(control);
      break;
    case // other control types
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, let me try it out. somehow, sound like the right direction. I will leave it open for more suggestions. Once I get it successful I will mark it as solved.